# Refresh Controllers/Views after Database Change in MVC4 Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

My DBA decided to rename some fields in the database, so I refreshed my EF data context.

Now I'm wondering if I need to delete / re-create my controllers and views or if I can 'refresh' them without deleting (since I've made modifications to my controllers).  Either option would be faster than hand editing in the changes, since there's quite a few.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How far does refactor-rename get you?

Comment: I may go that route - but there's a ton of names to do.  I was curious if there's a practice in place for database changes in a database first application.  I figured it was a long shot, but worth checking.

Comment: I'm not aware of any magical tool. Especially since _I've made modifications to my controllers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be... The model can only update entity classes, not views and controllers.

A trick for could be to creating a new controller with a new name and keeping the old controller as well. Then, copy those important codes from the old contoller to the new one.

And the same approach for views